# How to remove constant part of a signal in python?

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a dataset where it is constant sometimes with small noise. It can be on the top, it can be in the middle. I want to remove all constant part of the signal so that it compress into a smaller length.

Lets say if 200 consicutive value is same (or in a threshold limit to be considered as constant) then consider that part as constant .

Any solution code or logical suggestion will be appriciated.
Thanks for your time.

I have attached a [sample data google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u7lSiryjmPVXOKgoslbnUE1lKVIqINIZ/view?usp=sharing) in .npy format.

In the below sample image I have indicated (red) which part I want to get rid of as an example:

[image]

Comment: I didn't exactly get what do you need. You have to remove all the constant values (where constant = 200 or more consecutive observation with same value), delete all of them but one or delete them from the 201st to the end?

Comment: @Federicofkt   Thanks for asking more clarification. I want to delete all value which are relatively constant. The defination of constant in my case is: Atleast 200 data points has to be in same value.

Comment: what approaches did you try so far?

Comment: I followed the approach from @rsenne answered. But it did not fullfil my target that want to achieve. Probably initiating a counter would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution. The answer from @rsenne helped me to start but that was not the solution I have wanted. Please let me know if there anything I should add in my solution to improve the performance.

```
import numpy as np

def remove_flat_segments(data, threshold, min_length):
       
       """
       Remove flat segments from data within a threshold and with a minimum length.
    
       Parameters:
        data (ndarray): Input data array.
        threshold (float): Threshold for flatness.
        min_length (int): Minimum length of flat segment to be removed.
    
       Returns:
        ndarray: Data with flat segments removed.
       """
    flat_segments = []
    start_idx = None
    
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if start_idx is None:
            start_idx = i
        elif abs(data[i] - data[i-1]) > threshold:
            if i - start_idx >= min_length:
                flat_segments.append((start_idx, i-1))
            start_idx = None
    
    if start_idx is not None and len(data) - start_idx >= min_length:
        flat_segments.append((start_idx, len(data)-1))
    
    if len(flat_segments) > 0:
        flat_indices = np.concatenate([np.arange(start, end+1) for start, end in flat_segments])
        return np.delete(data, flat_indices)
    else:
        return data


threshold = 0.01
min_length = 1000

filtered_data = remove_flat_segments(data, threshold, min_length)
```

The resulted image looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution but this just slides a 200 length window over the signal, looks at the variance, and any variance over a specific magnitude is considered non-constant. There is probably ways this could be modified but with very little effort I was able to remove a lot of the constant.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.load(r"C:\Users\ryansenne\Downloads\sample.npy")

# Detects constant sections and removes them
def remove_constant_sections(signal, window_size=200, threshold=0.01):
    filtered_signal = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(signal) - window_size:
        window = signal[i:i+window_size]
        if np.var(window) > threshold:
            filtered_signal.extend(window)
            i += window_size
        else:
            i += 1
    # Add the remaining values that may not fit into a full window
    filtered_signal.extend(signal[i:])
    return np.array(filtered_signal)


filtered_signal = remove_constant_sections(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The solution is almost what I have wanted. Additionally I want remove the window data itself also. So that there will be no gap between two consecutive cycle. At present solution there is 200 data points (equal to window) remains between two cycles.

Comment: so, adjust the slice. give it a try.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Slice adjustment will reduce or increase the gap between two consecutive cycle but will not totally eliminate the gap. 
Maybe sliding window method is suitable for my solution.

Comment: you can get something working based on the idea of this answer. I grant you, this answer is doing trivial things like chopping only full windows out of the signal. i could instead use that window approach to find out where flat segments start and end...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your idea. You  may can write your solution as answer. I will mark your answer as accepted.